# Postfix: 'Relay access denied' - all incoming mail is rejected

Tags: postfix

I am testing my PostFix setup by sending email from my gmail account to an account on a virtual domain. Postfix's response is invariably:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lb0-f177.google.com[209.85.217.177]: 454 4.7.1 <mailATbrokkr.net>: Relay access denied; from=<madspayATgmail.com> to=<mailATbrokkr.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lb0-f177.google.com>
```

Here is the main.cf configuration file:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/nginx/certs/madsmide_ssl-unified.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/nginx/certs/madsmide_ssl.key
#smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
#smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination

# host configuration
myhostname = mail.madsmi.de
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydomain = madsmi.de
myorigin = $mydomain

# Local domain mapping
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
#alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#mydestination = localhost
mydestination =

# Virtal domain mapping
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/my_virtual_mailbox_domains
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/my_virtual_mailbox_maps
virtual_uid_maps = static:128
virtual_gid_maps = static:142
#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

# Unknown
#relayhost = 
mailbox_size_limit = 1000000000
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

Here is the my_virtual_mailbox_domains file:

```
madsmi.de
#madskas.dk
brokkr.net
```

and the my_virtual_mailbox_maps file:

```
mailATmadsmi.de          madsmi.de/mail/
mailATbrokkr.net         brokkr.net/mail/
```

Here's a more detailed debug log from one connection attempt:

```
Jun 20 22:59:09 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: send attr request = seed
Jun 20 22:59:09 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: send attr size = 32
Jun 20 22:59:09 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: status
Jun 20 22:59:09 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: input attribute name: status
Jun 20 22:59:09 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: input attribute value: 0
Jun 20 22:59:09 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: seed
Jun 20 22:59:09 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: input attribute name: seed
Jun 20 22:59:09 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: input attribute value: h+12lK71F0Vgl8z8GN3zJmF2Sgcja/Y7rqFz1BV4raw=
Jun 20 22:59:09 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jun 20 22:59:09 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: input attribute name: (end)
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: < mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: EHLO mail-lb0-f180.google.com
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_list_match: mail-lb0-f180.google.com: no match
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_list_match: 209.85.217.180: no match
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 250-mail.madsmi.de
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 250-PIPELINING
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 250-SIZE 10240000
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 250-VRFY
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 250-ETRN
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 250-8BITMIME
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 250 DSN
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: < mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: MAIL FROM:<madspayATgmail.com> SIZE=4079
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: extract_addr: input: <madspayATgmail.com>
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=madspayATgmail.com
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: ctable_locate: move existing entry key madspayATgmail.com
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: extract_addr: in: <madspayATgmail.com>, result: madspayATgmail.com
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: smtpd_check_rewrite: trying: permit_inet_interfaces
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: permit_inet_interfaces: mail-lb0-f180.google.com 209.85.217.180
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: fsspace: .: block size 4096, blocks free 37725053
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: smtpd_check_queue: blocks 4096 avail 37725053 min_free 0 msg_size_limit 10240000
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 250 2.1.0 Ok
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: < mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: RCPT TO:<mailATmadsmi.de>
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: extract_addr: input: <mailATmadsmi.de>
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=mailATmadsmi.de
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: ctable_locate: move existing entry key mailATmadsmi.de
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: extract_addr: in: <mailATmadsmi.de>, result: mailATmadsmi.de
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: >>> START Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: permit_mynetworks: mail-lb0-f180.google.com 209.85.217.180
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostname: mail-lb0-f180.google.com ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostaddr: 209.85.217.180 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostname: mail-lb0-f180.google.com ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostaddr: 209.85.217.180 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostname: mail-lb0-f180.google.com ~? [::1]/128
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostaddr: 209.85.217.180 ~? [::1]/128
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_list_match: mail-lb0-f180.google.com: no match
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_list_match: 209.85.217.180: no match
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks status=0
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: generic_checks: name=permit_sasl_authenticated
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: generic_checks: name=permit_sasl_authenticated status=0
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: generic_checks: name=defer_unauth_destination
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: reject_unauth_destination: mailATmadsmi.de
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: permit_auth_destination: mailATmadsmi.de
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key mailATmadsmi.de
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 454 4.7.1 <mailATmadsmi.de>: Relay access denied; from=<madspayATgmail.com> to=<mailATmadsmi.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lb0-f180.google.com>
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: generic_checks: name=defer_unauth_destination status=2
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: >>> END Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 454 4.7.1 <mailATmadsmi.de>: Relay access denied
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: < mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: DATA
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: < mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: QUIT
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: > mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 221 2.0.0 Bye
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostname: mail-lb0-f180.google.com ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostaddr: 209.85.217.180 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostname: mail-lb0-f180.google.com ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostaddr: 209.85.217.180 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostname: mail-lb0-f180.google.com ~? [::1]/128
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_hostaddr: 209.85.217.180 ~? [::1]/128
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_list_match: mail-lb0-f180.google.com: no match
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: match_list_match: 209.85.217.180: no match
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: send attr request = disconnect
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: send attr ident = smtp:209.85.217.180
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: input attribute name: status
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: input attribute value: 0
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: input attribute name: (end)
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: disconnect from mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: master_notify: status 1
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: connection closed
```

My question is: Why are the mails being rejected? From what little I can gather from the log, either the sender (google.com) is found wanting or the recipient (in this case: mail at madsmi.de) is not recognised.

If it's the first, I'm confused about why relay rules are applied when the host is the destination and not being asked to send the mail on but to deliver it. If it's the second why can't PostFix see the recipient in virtual_mailbox_maps?

Comment: I'm not sure why [`reject_unauth_destination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unauth_destination) is triggered, as the domain `brokkr.net` is in [`virtual_mailbox_domains`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_domains). Btw: Why don't you leave `mydestination` at it's default value? Otherwise you will get problems with local mail delivery.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because of the "hash:" below, remove it and it will pass.

## Virtal domain mapping

virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/my_virtual_mailbox_domains

Answer (score -1):

mydestination cannot be empty. The mailserver cannot find any destinations for the mail because this field is empty. In essence NOQUEUE it has nowhere to go.
I would set this to  mydestination = 127.0.0.1 or even localhost should work fine. defer_unauth_destination means that it is not setup as a backup MX server either. The only time that mydestination should be empty is if you are acting as a backup MX server. In that case you need to setup relayhost as the server you are acting as a backup for.

Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lb0-f180.google.com[209.85.217.180]: 454 4.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: generic_checks: name=defer_unauth_destination status=2
Jun 20 22:59:10 THEMINT postfix/smtpd[10294]: >>> END Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<